# Graphics on C# Trying to draw a line on a Canvas

Tags: c#, graphics

Can't get this drawing a line on Visual Studio. It outputs the console commands but doesn't draw anything. Not too sure what is going on.. Am I missing somethinng? I've followed all the tutorials my lecturer has set out but it's just not having it.

Below is the Canvas Code and then Form code respectively.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace AssignmentProper
{
    public class Canvass
    {
        Graphics g;
        Pen Pen;
        int xPos, yPos;

        public Canvass(Graphics g)
        {
            this.g = g;
            xPos = yPos = 0;
            Pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        }


        public void DrawLine(int toX, int toY)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pen, xPos, yPos, toX, toY);
            xPos = toX;
            yPos = toY;
        }

        public void DrawSquare(int width)
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(Pen, xPos, yPos, xPos + width, yPos + width);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AssignmentProper
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap OutputBitmap = new Bitmap(640, 480);
        Canvass MyCanvass;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyCanvass = new Canvass(Graphics.FromImage(OutputBitmap));
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    
        }

        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void commandLine_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("key down");
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                String Command = commandLine.Text.Trim().ToLower();

                if(Command.Equals("line") == true)
                {
                    MyCanvass.DrawLine(160, 120);
                    Console.WriteLine("LINE");
                }
                else if (Command.Equals("square") == true)
                {
                    MyCanvass.DrawSquare(25);
                    Console.WriteLine("SQUARE");
                }
                commandLine.Text = "";
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.DrawImageUnscaled(OutputBitmap, 0, 0);
        }

    }
}
```

No idea what's going on, it's just simply not drawing anything. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but the code works for me.

Comment: I demonstrate how to draw on a canvas, and a few other things in this video tutorial. https://youtu.be/TYpuuCMTmrY

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Do you have any idea what could possibly be wrong on my end?

Comment: Is the paint event actually connected to the picture box?

Comment: I've got no idea, how do I check?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see if the debugger enter the event!